# Alternative way instead of iterating over rows for getting a list of average values

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, rows

I have two data frames like below:-

```
data ={'a':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7],'b':[2,5,3,6,1,7,4]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df
    a   b
0   1   2
1   2   5
2   3   3
3   4   6
4   5   1
5   6   7
6   7   4
data ={'a':[4,2,1,7,3,6,5],'c':[12,15,13,60,100,700,400]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data)
df1
    a   c
0   4   12
1   2   15
2   1   13
3   7   60
4   3   100
5   6   700
6   5   400
```

Now I want a list of values using the above two data frames. Basically, I want to search the `df` row values in `df1` and get the corresponding value (column `c` of `df1`) and append them into a list by taking the average of both numbers.

However, I was able to do it but as I am iterating over rows it is taking time. Is there any better way to get the solution much faster?

code:

```
final=[]
for index, row in edges.iterrows():
    for inde2x, row2 in df1.iterrows():
        if np.isin(row['a'],row2['a']) == True: 
            r1 = row2['c']
        if np.isin(row['b'],row2['a']) == True:
            r2 = row2['c']
    final.apped(r1+r2)
print(final)
```

Excepted output:

```
[28, 415, 200, 712, 413, 760, 72]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is stack the values of `df`, map it using the `a` columns from `df1`:

```
out = df.stack().map(df1.set_index('a')['c']).groupby(level=0).sum()
```

Output:

```
0     28
1    415
2    200
3    712
4    413
5    760
6     72
dtype: int64
```

If you need a list, you can do `out.tolist()`

Answer (score 1):

Use `map`

```
mapper = df1.set_index('a').c.to_dict()    
print(df['a'].map(mapper) + df['b'].map(mapper))
```

---

```
0     28
1    415
2    200
3    712
4    413
5    760
6     72
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

```
d = df1.set_index("a")
df.applymap(lambda x: d.loc[x, "c"]).sum(1)
# 0     28
# 1    415
# 2    200
# 3    712
# 4    413
# 5    760
# 6     72
# dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution using a lookup based on `merge`

```
res = sum(df.merge(df1, left_on=col, right_on='a', how='left')['c'] for col in 'ab').tolist()
```

Output:

```
>>> res

[28, 415, 200, 712, 413, 760, 72]
```